# Install problem for a first timer

Tags: boot, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu for the first time on my spare hard drive and I'm running into an error. I put the .iso on a USB using Universal USB Installer 1.9.6.1 and booted from the USB. When I try to run it without installing, install, or check for problems, I get this error.

[image]

I have Windows 10 on my SSD and I'm trying to put Ubuntu on my unused hard drive. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try to unplug all other USB devices if any.

Comment: The only other USB I have plugged in is my mouse. When I unplugged that and tried I got the same error with less lines - none of them said usb 9-3. I think it has something to do with my USB ports, which sucks. I did manage to get on Ubuntu once (after about 50 tries) but my mouse was unresponsive and I didn't know any commands to help get it installed. Thanks for the help though, you were definitely on to something. Any other guesses?